# Sudden IM004 and 08001 errors in a PHP + Sqlsrv intranet site

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, iis-7.5, sqlsrv

So.. a bit of a rundown? I've had a PHP 5.5 + IIS 7.5 + SQL Server 2008 (running in Windows Server 2008) project working since 2015; never experienced what started happening since the beginning of the year. Randomly, the connection will drop and **nothing** will bring it back until we do an app pool recycle in IIS.

The most common error is:

```
[0] => IM004
            [SQLSTATE] => IM004
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed
```

But we've also gotten hit with this nasty combo a few times:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => 21
            [code] => 21
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Encryption not supported on the client.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Encryption not supported on the client.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => -2146893052
            [code] => -2146893052
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => 21
            [code] => 21
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => -2146893052
            [code] => -2146893052
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
        )
```

The latter is literally telling me it can't connect, which would lead anyone to say "Ok, you've an issue with your SQL Server" but since an app pool recycle brings back everything up to speed that can't be the case. Furthermore, since it happens randomly, it's not like users weren't working fine in the first place, meaning that the connection to the server is just fine.

Making this more obscure is the fact this project isn't something new that we just started, it's something that we have been developing and using since 2015 and this didn't start happening until a month ago. For a bit more than a week between Jan 9 to Jan 18 no error happened while the userload has been the same. Reading about IM004 on the net we've tried reinstalling the ODBC driver for SQL Server 11 but it didn't change a thing. Some may want to suggest moving to PHP 7 with the updated Sqlsrv library and all but that isn't an option *right now*, given the size of the project and the amount of resources it'd take to do it in a timely fashion.

We have not introduced anything new to the server other than updates to the intranet app; that also lead us to consider maybe we dropped some kind of murderous query or process but when we started logging the query that'd start triggering the issue we found that it happened with whatever queries as well as ranging from complex ones to something as harmless as a "SET dateformat ymd".

I'm at my wits' end with this on account that there doesn't seem to be much documentation about it within this context. I've tried asking on Microsoft's forums both from a IIS + PHP angle as well as from the Sqlsrv library's angle but never got any answers because I'm pretty sure people aren't sure what's up.

Any kind of hindsight on this issue in regards to what could be going on or what could I possibly do to fix it will be greatly appreciated since, at this point, I just can't think of anything else to try and the situation has become nightmarish.

Edit: so, while I imagined nothing would change (why would it?), I updated the entire site to PHP 7.3.14 with its respective new SQLSrv extension and ODBC driver 17. The issue persists:

[16-Feb-2020 13:05:21 America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires] PHP Warning:  Failed to make connection to database in C:...\ezsql\lib\Database\ez_sqlsrv.php on line 112 in C:...\ezsql\lib\ezsqlModel.php on line 225
Stack trace:

## 0 C:...\ezsql\lib\Database\ez_sqlsrv.php(319): ezsql\Database\ez_sqlsrv->connect('user', 'pass', 'database', 'host')

## 1 C:...\db.php(23): ezsql\Database\ez_sqlsrv->query('SET dateformat ...')

## 2 C:...\ajax_html.php(5): require_once('C:\inetpub\wwwr...')

When that happens, it gets stuck from 10 minutes to up to one hour unless we perform an app pool recycle. Then everything goes back to normal. We attempted to connect to the SQL database through the SQL Management Studio before doing so and we had no issues whatsoever, which means it's not a database issue.

At this point I'm literally **desperate** since there's nothing worse than not understanding an issue. If there's anything anyone can think of that is related to this I'll be extremely grateful.

Comment: Out of interest, why is everythingm you listed that you're using all end of life software?  PHP 5.5 has been unsupported for a few years, SQL Server 2008 support ran out in Summer of last year, and IIS 7.5 is part of Windows Server 2008; which ran out of support last month. You really should be looking at upgrade paths.

Comment: Well, the project wasn't started last year. It was started more than 6 years ago. Naturally, migrating to latest version of PHP is a priority eventually, the rest requires money and that's not up to me.

That said, none of that is really relevant to my issue since this project has been running this long without its actual issue. So I really can't focus on thinking about upgrading when I've a huge project that is experiencing an issue unrelated to versioning that I can't figure out.

Comment: But if you don't upgrade, how can you tell if the issue has already been fixed in later releases? End-of-life products won't receive bug fixes, and have huge security risks in the meantime, so you should plan upgrade months/years in advance. For right now, do migration as quickly as possible, and accept the issue (as you knew it for a month now).

Comment: I posted a reply to this last comment and I've no idea why it was deleted but I'll say this again: that's no answer. That's dodging an issue. Nonetheless, we've updated PHP and the issue persists, which is to be expected since we never understood what this random issue was in the first place. So.. I'd appreciate if anyone could contribute something that is related to the issue in order for me to figure out what's going on.